# How i can insert local document in my collection?

Tags: mongodb

I wish I could add a document with its contents in my collection but I can not find the line I need to write.
I guess it looks like that but I can not find it.

db.documents.insert( ... )

Comment: The  [Getting Started tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/) in the MongoDB documentation would be a good starting point for the basics of working with documents. You could also check out the free online courses at [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/) (the next session of [M001 (MongoDB Basics)](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about) just started this week). There are also GUIs for MongoDB (for example [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)) that are easier than working with JavaScript directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does look [like that](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/):

```
db.collection.insert(<document or array of documents>)
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I pass the contents of the document?
db.collection.insert(title:'test', content:'path'); ?

Comment: You know it's javascript right? So you have to use curly braces to specify an object, the same way it is represented when mongo shell displays documents